# to create a button when pressed print the number on that button in the entry box in python 3.3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-8, tkinter

i want to make a button on which '2' is written .... now when anyone click it , it will show the number '2' in the entry box... 
the error  is:
before clicking , it is already showing '2' in  the entry box

So please help me removing this error
here is my program

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()  
def add(x):  
    e1=Entry(root)  
    e1.insert(INSERT, x)  
    e1.pack()

a=Button(root, text='2', command=add(2))  
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a function (used `lambda` in the following code) instead of return value of the function.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()  
e1 = Entry(root)  
e1.pack()

def add(x):  
    e1.insert(INSERT, x)  

a = Button(root, text='2', command=lambda: add(2))
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In addition to that, extract Entry creation code out of the `add` function. Otherwise entry are create every time when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
a=Button(root, text='2', command=add(2))
```

it is the same as:

```
add(2)
a=Button(root, text='2', command=None)
```

i.e. you are calling `add` and assigning its `return` value to `command`. Instead, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a function that will call `add` with the argument `2`:

```
from functools import partial

a=Button(root, text='2', command=partial(add, 2))
```