# Python Tkinter Button Action

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import tkMessageBox

root = Tkinter.Tk()

def getFileName():
  # show an "Open" dialog box.
  filename = askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Text files', '*.txt'),('All files','*')])

btnIco = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Icon", command=getFileName())
btnIco.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I intended to do was to run the function `getFileName` when the button is clicked. But instead the function runs when the code is run and the button does not do anything when clicked. Can you please point out what is wrong?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23936127/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
btnIco = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Icon", command=getFileName())
```

with:

```
btnIco = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Icon", command=getFileName)
```

In other word, remove `()` after `getFileName`. By appending `()`, the code is call `getFileName` before creating the button, and use the return value of the function as a callback instead of the function itself.